# Fix vs. Fix_sub

Tags: coq

I'm attempting to use `Fix` to express a well-founded function.
It has `Fix_eq` to unwrap it for 1 level, however, the confusing
part is that `Fix_eq` is expressed in terms of `Fix_sub` instead of `Fix`.
The difference appears to be that

```
Check Fix.
(* ... *)
       (forall x : A, (forall y : A, R y x -> P y) -> P x) ->

Check Fix_sub.
(* ... *)
       (forall x : A, (forall y : {y : A | R y x}, P (proj1_sig y)) -> P x) ->
```

`Fix` uses 2 arguments and `Fix_sub` packages them both together into a `sig`.
So, they are essentially equivalent.  However, I don't see any included
convenience functions to switch between `Fix` and `Fix_sub`.  Is there
a reason that `Fix_eq` doesn't work with `Fix` ?  How is it supposed
to be used?

I'm aware of `Program` and `Function`, but here I am trying to use `Fix` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version and libraries are you using?

in 8.16 I get

```
Fix_eq:
  forall [A : Type] [R : A -> A -> Prop] (Rwf : well_founded R)
    (P : A -> Type) (F : forall x : A, (forall y : A, R y x -> P y) -> P x),
  (forall (x : A) (f g : forall y : A, R y x -> P y),
   (forall (y : A) (p : R y x), f y p = g y p) -> F x f = F x g) ->
  forall x : A, Fix Rwf P F x = F x (fun (y : A) (_ : R y x) => Fix Rwf P F y)
```

and `Fib_sub`is unknown.

You may have imported some module which masks the definitions from Coq.Init.Wf ?

Comment: Thank you!  For reference, I'm on Coq 8.13.2, but that's not the problem.  Somehow, when I searched for "Coq Fix_eq", I found 
https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Program.Wf.html#Fix_eq
instead of
https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Wf.html#Fix_eq
So, I started using the wrong library, which, as you stated, shadowed everything.  So, I can just not import that library.  I can also use the fully qualified name `Coq.Init.Wf.Fix_eq` if needed.

Comment: Ok, or just `Init.Wf.Fix_eq`, as suggested by `Locate`.